# Personal statement in SO CV can not be deleted

Tags: bug, stack-overflow-jobs

I Wrote something in my Personal statement section, but now I'm not satisfied with and I don't have time to change it now, I decided to remove the Personal statement and when I have enough time I write new one. But Since in order to save the personal statement should have at least 200 characters, I'm can no longer remove it.

Is this an issue, or it’s intentionally made this way? I think we should have the ability to remove the section and in same time it keeps the requirement of 200 characters when it's not empty.

How can I remove my current Personal statement?

Comment: Does the old HTML comment trick work? `<!-- (200 random characters) -->`

Comment: Yes it works, but the blue block still show up, which does not look nice.

Answer (score 7):

When a protocol imposes a minimum message length, take inspiration from the original Ethernet and pad!

Minimum length rules are silly and counterproductive. A short message is better than one with the same semantic content plus useless padding.

`length(str) >= 15` is easy to implement, but a poor substitute for `quality_score(str) >= 0.85`.

Comment: ...........like this!

Comment: &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;+1

Comment: I think part of the OP's problem, judging by their comment under the question, is _also_ wanting the block that holds it to go away, which this trick won't cause.

Comment: The blue block still show up, which does not look nice.